# Brownian Motion and Hitting Time expectation.

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

The problem is as follows:

Let $(W_t)$ be a Brownian Motion, $\alpha>0$, and $\tau = \inf\{t>0 : W_t \geq \alpha\}$ be the First Exit Time.

Compute $\mathbb{E}(\tau)$.

I am aware that the result is not finite, however I am having trouble showing that the integral does not converge.

This problem has answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531225/expected-hitting-time-of-given-level-by-brownian-motion). However they use results I haven't seen or understand, such as Wald's Identities.

**What I have done so far:**

$$
\mathbb{P}(\tau \leq t) 
= \mathbb{P}(W_t^* \geq \alpha)
= 2 \cdot \mathbb{P}(W_t \geq \alpha)
= 2(1- \Phi(\alpha / \sqrt{t}))
$$

Where $W_t^* = \underset{0\leq s \leq t}{\sup} W_s$.

$$
f(t) 
= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \mathbb{P}(\tau \leq t)
= 2\phi\left(\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{t}}\right)\left(\frac{\alpha}{2 \sqrt{t^3}}\right)
= \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}} e^{-\frac{1}{2t}\alpha^2}
$$

I am stuck here:

$$
\mathbb{E}(\tau)
= \int_0^{\infty} t \cdot \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}} e^{-\frac{1}{2t}\alpha^2} dt
\overset{?}{=} \infty
$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know whether your expression is correct, but
$$\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty} t \cdot \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}} e^{-\frac{1}{2t}\alpha^2} dt \\
\ge &\int_1^{\infty} t \cdot \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}} e^{-\frac{1}{2t}\alpha^2} dt \qquad\text{ shortening the integral}\\
\ge &\int_1^{\infty} t \cdot \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2} dt  \qquad\text{ since } e^{-\frac{1}{2t}\alpha^2} \text{ is an increasing function of } t\\
= &\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2}\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}  dt\\
= &+\infty
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you. Does the working look incorrect somewhere ?